# Как создать клавиатуру (кнопки) telegram бота

Tags: telegram-bot, aiogram, клавиатура

Начал писать телеграмм бота на основе aiogram. Это мой первый бот, поэтому возникли вопросы.
Бот структурирован по папкам - handlers, keyboard, data_base и т.д.

Возникла проблема с кнопками (не инлайн). Изначальный код кнопок:

```
#@dp.message_handler(commands=['Наш_сайт'])
async def site_command(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'text')
#@dp.message_handler(commands=['Instagram'])
async def inst_command(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'text')
```

'#' стоит, потому что в конце кода все хэндлеры зарегистрированы -

```
def register_handlers_client(dp: Dispatcher):
dp.register_message_handler(site_command, commands=['Наш_сайт'])
```

Код кнопок в кейборде был: b1 = KeyboardButton('/Наш_сайт'). Но мне не понравилось, что кнопка выглядят так, т.е. имеются символы / и _. Изменил кнопки на b1 = KeyboardButton('Наш сайт').
Переписал код в следующий:

```
@dp.message_handler()
async def bot_message(message: types.Message):
    if message.text == 'Наш сайт':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'text')
    elif message.text == 'Instagram':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'text')
```

И вроде бы все хорошо, кнопки исправились, при отправке отвечает верно. Но возникла другая проблема. У меня в хэндлерах и кейбордах для админа есть команда /moderator (для загрузки и удаления товаров каталога), которую я пишу в группу, а отвечает мне у бота.

```
#@dp.message_handler(commands=['moderator'], is_chat_admin=True)
async def make_changes_command(message: types.Message):
    global ID
    ID = message.from_user.id
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Чего изволите?', reply_markup=admin_kb.button_case_admin)
    await message.delete()
```

Когда я писал первый вариант кнопок - /moderator работал, когда переписал на второй вариант кнопок  - /moderator перестала отвечать/работать.
Искал проблему в хэндлерах, кейбордах, но так и не смог понять, почему при втором варианте кнопок /moderator перестает работать.
В чем может быть проблема? ошибок при этом никаких не выдает